# simple dom parser double find() doesn't work?

Tags: php, dom, simpledom

[image]

Above is my DOM and I expect to get 4 hour ago but I got an error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object
```

My php look like this

```
$time_ago = $html->find('.entry .unvoted',0)->find('.tagline .live-timestamp',0)->plaintext;

echo $time_ago;
```

I know I could do with one find(), which will be `find('tagline .live-timestamp')` but I wonder why double find() doesn't work.

Comment: 1. are you sure it isn't the first `find` that crashes (which means `$html` is empty) ? 2. are you sure your first `find` actually finds something ?

Comment: Why don't you use `DOMXPath`?

Answer (score 0):

I got it work by this

```
$time_ago = $go->find('.entry',0)->find('.tagline .live-timestamp',0)->plaintext;
```

because there's more than one class called `unvoted`